# Cifrar contraseña con llave pública Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, encriptación, cifrado, rsa

estoy intentando cifrar una contraseña con una llave pública que estoy leyendo de un archivo... el problema es que no logro hacerlo de la manera correcta debido a que en el servidor donde se decifra con la llave privada no me reconoce el cifrado que realicé...

Mí código es el siguiente:

```
String publicKey = "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";
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(publicKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedBytes;
        pass = getPassword().getValue();
        encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes());
        pass = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

La contraseña que estoy enviando al servidor es la que almacena la variable pass que se supone que está cifrada con el algoritmo RSA a través de la llave pública que contiene la variable publicKey.

Teniendo en cuenta que a la llave pública ya le eliminé el ---BEGIN PUBLIC KEY--/--END PUBLIC KEY--.

Por alguna razón el cifrado no está funcionando y me está arrojando 202 debido a que la contraseña que estoy mandando es incorrecta(porque no está bien cifrada) tienen alguna idea de cómo realizar el cifrado de manera correcta, o qué error tiene el código mostrado anteriormente.

Comment: Yo he tenido problemas con "RSA", prefiero usar "AES", es forzoso usar "RSA" como algoritmo para ti?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor desencriptado crea un `String` con codificación "UTF-8":

```
  ...
  ...
  pass = getPassword().getValue();
  encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes());

  String valorDesencriptado new String(encryptedBytes,"UTF-8");
  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

espero no sea muy tarde, también pase por el mismo problema y aquí les dejo dos códigos para encriptación de usuario y contraseña(bueno en realidad de lo que quieran), el primer código es una encriptación simple lo pueden usar sin dificultad alguna y les dejo un segundo código por si quieren publicar su App en Play Store(actualmente las políticas cambiaron y piden mas cosas para subir una aplicación, una de ellas es que el cifrado no sea "AES/ECB/NoPadding/PKCS5Padding/ISO10126Padding",  mi aplicación la suspendieron y estoy cambiando justo eso y estamos en gestión) :

1.- Encriptación simple:

```
public SecretKeySpec GenerateKey (String password) throws  Exception
    {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); //512
        //md.update(salt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] key = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        key =  messageDigest.digest(key);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
        return secretKeySpec;
    }

    public String Encriptar (String datos) throws  Exception
    {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = GenerateKey(datos);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec);
        byte[] DatosEncriptados = cipher.doFinal(datos.getBytes());
        String DatosString = Base64.encodeToString(DatosEncriptados, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return DatosString;
    }
```

1.1. Para Llamar desde cualquier parte

```
String NewEncripUser = null;
                        String NewEncripPass = null;
                        try {
                            NewEncripUser = Encriptar(edtUser.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                            NewEncripPass = Encriptar(edtClave.getText().toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

2.- Encriptación MD5

```
  public static String GenerateKey (String dato){
        try{
            MessageDigest messageDigest =java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); //512
            messageDigest.update(dato.getBytes());
            byte message[]= messageDigest.digest();
            StringBuilder hexstring = new StringBuilder();
            for(byte aMessageDig : message)
                hexstring.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDig));
            return hexstring.toString();
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

2.1. Para Llamar desde cualquier parte

```
String EncripSaveUser = edtUser.getText().toString();
String EncripSavePass= edtClave.getText().toString();
EncripSaveUser=GenerateKey(EncripSaveUser);
EncripSavePass=GenerateKey(EncripSavePass);
Log.i("EncripSaveUser01",EncripSaveUser);
Log.i("EncripSavePass02",EncripSavePass);
```